# Python фреймворк для 2d игр

Tags: python, framework, pygame, opengl

Привет всем! Решил написать простенькую игрушку, осуществить свою мечту детства, взялся изучать `pygame`. Он конечно, крут, то мне нужен рендеринг через `opengl`, а с ним `pygame` прозрачно работать не умеет, в следствии чего нужно погружаться в эти дебри с `opengl api`. Если Я туда залезу, то долго еще не вылезу, пока буду писать свой велосипед ;[ Посоветуйте, пожалуйста

Есть ли какой нибудь фреймворк для создания 2d игр на питоне, при этом, чтобы рендеринг производился используя `opengl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть [Kivy](http://kivy.org) подойдет?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Посмотрел документацию, и пришел к выводу, что предложенный вами вариант слишком высокоуровневый.

В идеале, хотелось бы что-нибудь похожее на pygame, т.е., чтобы там был только инструментарий для работы со спрайтами, звуком, может быть, физикой, а MainLoop, обработку событий нужно было создавать самому.

Comment: Посмотрите среди этих, может что-то и подберете  https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries

Comment: Спасибо!) Скорее всего все-таки, придется допиливать pyGame ;]